# Change picture source of an <img> doesn't work with variable

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use my image tag `id="bla" src="....."` in my web page by changing dynamically the `src` parameter. I usually do that with a selector and setting the `src` property, i.e.

```
$("#bla").prop("src", "/new/image/path.png")
```

but today I wanted to follow another way :

```
var bullet = $("#bla");  
bullet.src = "/new/image/path.png";
```

I expected that code change my picture in my HTML page, but it doesn't happen.
The statement doesn't produce any error and if I watch my `bullet.src` value I find the new path for the new picture.
If I query  `$("#bla").prop("src")` I find the old path, could somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Try `var bullet = $("#blah")[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
var bullet = $("#bla");
```

`bullet` will be an array of `<img ..` element. When you do change any attributes on that, it will not change.

You can do any of these, and change their property:

```
var bullet = $("#bla")[0];
// or
var bullet = $("#bla").get(0);

bullet.src = "/new/image/path.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bla').attr('src','/new/image/path.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
bullet.attr('src', '/new/image/path.png');
```